# Cant choose the right networking solution for my Java app

Tags: java, network-programming

I am writing a distributed Java application that will make heavy use of networking, and that needs to be **fast**.

Let's pretend that I have a class called *Widget*. Widgets are created client-side (most likely a Swing box) but will need to be persisted server-side and shared/distributed amongst all the other connected clients. So, I need a way to serialize Widget instances, send them to the server, where the server will manage them and update all connected clients with state changes in the Widgets they are interested in. (So, once a Widget is created and sent server-side, it can theoretically be "pulled down" and modified by any other client.

Performance is a must, so this must be a binary protocol. Also would prefer non-blocking sockets, and something that is very, very scalable.

So I'm looking at RMI, NIO and Netty as feasible solutions. If I understand Java networking correctly, then everything seems to indicate the RMI is considerably slower than NIO. I've also heard RMI is lacking in the scalability department. NIO on the other hand, gives you more flexibility and thus is considerably more complicated.  Netty seems to have the best documentation, but seems slower than NIO and may not be capable of what I really need it to do.

For Widget distribution, I'm simply looking for the ability to send Widgets over a network, and fast. Don't care what protocols are used.

Anyone care to share their thoughts/input?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned Netty. I would second that. My experience with Netty was great. It's a very efficient library with solid documentation and flexibility.

It can do anything you can imagine with binary protocols, yet it only does what you need, so it's lightweight. It also scales very well. I've successfully load tested a single server with a simple job sustaining over 10k+ request/sec for 200-300 concurrent clients. That was on a fairly standard rack server.

There is a bit of a learning curve, but the javadoc is some of the best I've seen for dealing with that hurdle. The project is in active development, and the lead on the project is extremely responsive to questions and defects.

EDIT: For fast transfer of Widgets, you could look into Protocol Buffers. They are pretty efficient for serializing/de-serializing objects over the wire.

Comment: Thanks rfreak! I'll take that into consideration - those are some pretty big numbers.  Also, when I say that this is a networking application that uses distributed Widget objects, am I using the phrase "distributed" correctly? Or do "serialized", "distributed" or "networked" have different implications? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, RMI and NIO are apples to oranges; so don't mix up things that are not alternatives. Second, make sure performance really truly matters; and what kind of performance (throughput & latency being usual first candidates; or maybe space efficiency). There is a chance you are overestimating significance of performance, as with good solutions you are more likely to be bounded by network performance, not by endpoint (CPU) performance.

And if performance matters, have a look at [jvm-serializers](https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/wiki) to get one performance comparison of actual formats. Java serialization is used for RMI, for example.

Oh, btw, do not assume you must use a binary format. This is typically not a hard requirement; textual formats compress well and are easier to debug/troubleshoot, and process by other platforms, languages if need be.

Comment: StaxMan - thanks for the input. I seem to be missing something basic when it comes to understanding the difference between RMI and NIO. As I understand it, both are sockets-based. Whereas NIO allows you to implement anything on top of TCP or UDP, RMI almost seems to have its own application-layer protocol for transporting serialized objects across a network. But doesn't this just boil down to 2 different socket-based protocols? What am I missing here? Unless the terms "serialized" and "networked" objects do not imply the same thing...

Comment: NIO is the low-level alternative to older blocking I/O ("BIO"). NIO just allows accessing sockets (and files etc) in non-blocking manner. Netty is a library that makes it easier to use NIO. And RMI just implements "black box" of not just tcp based send/receive but also object serialization and other related pieces. Serialization with RMI does include full serialization from any Java object to byte[] and back; I think serialization has other meanings in other contexts?

Comment: So: basically, RMI implements "all you need" and it's hard to replace pieces. NIO (with or without Netty) is a lower-level building block. You can use any of dozens of serialization schemes with NIO (or blocking I/O). If you like idea of RMI, you could consider RMI replacement DiRMI, http://sourceforge.net/projects/dirmi/, written by a senior Amazon engineer; it's "just like RMI, just better", addressing most known existing RMI issues.

Comment: Ahhhh.... so is it safe to say that in order to pass Widget over a network, it must first be serialized into bytes, and then RMI uses TCP sockets (based on NIO?) to pass the bytes over the network. Then, on the other end, RMI has the "black box" magic to reconstruct the bytes into Java objects. Is this a fair assessment?

Comment: Exactly. RMI implementation JDK uses may use NIO or blocking i/o (probably latter since NIO was added after RMI), but it is based on sockets either way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Jini](http://www.jini.org/wiki/What_is_Jini%3F) and [Javaspaces](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/tools/JavaSpaces/) ? It's RMI, so perhaps not suitable. But the space-based pattern is very powerful for distributing objects, receiving notifications, updating in a distributed fashion etc. and you can get something up and running very easily.

Comment: Brian, thanks for the suggestion - I'll take a look at Jini tonight.

Answer (score 0):

Both Google's [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) and [Apache Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) meet those criteria.

They are binary protocols for data serialization, and they have RPC APIs for passing your widgets over the network so that you do not have to reinvent the wheel.